# Spiral Animation JavaScript

Tags: javascript, animation

I am studying JavaScript and I discovered the following article: http://www.html5code.nl/tutorial-canvas-animation-spiral-movement/

Could you tell me how does the function spiralMotion1() works?
I would like to customize speed and distance.

edit: breaking it down to specifics: why use cos. and sin.? why use rotationRadius? how does the setAngle function influence the result? where does the degrees variable come into play?

the code:

```
function spiralMotion1(){
  var degrees = 0;
  var Angle;
  var rotationRadius=2;
  var rotationRadiusIncrease = 1;
  var ballRadius=20
  var centerX;
  var centerY;
  var x;
  var y;
  var animate=true;
  var breadcrumbs = new Array();
  var crumbRadius=1;
  var canvas = jQuery("#spiral_motion1");
  var context = canvas.get(0).getContext("2d");
  //function Ball(x,y,radius,color,strokeColor,lineWidth) in ball.js
  var ball_3 = new Ball(-10,-10,20,'#f00','#000',7);
  var parentWidth=jQuery(canvas).parent().width();
  var canvasWidth=context.canvas.width = parentWidth;
  var canvasHeight=context.canvas.height= 288;

  if (!checkForCanvasSupport) {
  return;
  }

  (function drawFrame() {
  window.requestAnimationFrame(drawFrame, canvas);


  if(animate){
  context.clearRect(0,0,canvasWidth,canvasHeight); // clear canvas
  //Make the Canvas element responsive for desktop, tablet and smartphone.
  centerX = canvasWidth/2;
  centerY = canvasHeight/2
  Angle = degrees * (Math.PI / 180);
  degrees = degrees + 1;
  ball_3.x=rotationRadius * Math.cos(setAngle()) + centerX;
  ball_3.y=rotationRadius * Math.sin(setAngle()) + centerY;
  ball_3.draw(context);

  //add a breadcrumb to the breadcrumbs array
  breadcrumbs.push({x:ball_3.x,y:ball_3.y});
  //draw the breadcrumbs that shows the track of the movement
  context.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-over";
  showBreadcrumbs(breadcrumbs);

  rotationRadius += rotationRadiusIncrease/5
  if ((ball_3.y + ballRadius+4) > canvas.height()){
  animate=false;
  }
  }
  }());//end drawFrame
 function setAngle(){
  Angle = degrees * (Math.PI / 180);
  degrees = degrees + 2;
  return Angle;
  }//end setAngl()

  function showBreadcrumbs(breadcrumbs){
  for (var i = 0; i< breadcrumbs.length; i++) {
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(breadcrumbs[i].x,breadcrumbs[i].y,crumbRadius,0, 2*Math.PI,false);
  context.closePath();
  context.fillStyle="#999";
  context.fill();
  }
  }//end showBreadcrumbs()
}//end spiralMotion1()
```

Comment: I would tell you but it´s pretty horrible and makes my head hurt.

Comment: thanks anyway, please check edit if you can answer more specific questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It boils down to basic geometry. If you think of a body orbiting a point in 2D, it's movement can be characterised by a radius (distance from the orbited point), and an angle which is a function of time. If you know the radius and the angle, then you can calculate the body position with the cos and sin function.

[image: Circular motion geometry]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrNdh.png)

By changing the radius over time, you obtain a spiral instead of a simple circle.

Comment: Thanks for the enlightenment, I think I can play around with it now.